# Elementary Differential Equations LInear operator question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If i let $a,b,c>0$ and $L=a(d^2/dt^2)+b(d/dt)+c$.  If $L[y_1]=g=L[y_2]$.

How would I show that $(y1-y2)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions to $Lu=g$. By linearity, $y_1-y_2$ is a solution to $Lu=0$. So you need to show any solution to $Lu=0$ tends to zero as $t \to \infty$. The key here is that any root of the characteristic equation has strictly negative real part. Consequently any solution to $Lu=0$, regardless of the initial conditions being required, decays exponentially to zero.